# filter data based on group completion data

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains groups of scheduled programs. Each group is represented by group_id and each program in the group depends on previous program to complete. But, I don't need to schedule anything if all the programs in that group are completed. So, I need to filter data if a group containing programs are all completed. order defines the order of the programs that need to be scheduled

```
id, group_id, trigger_group_id, trigger,  order
1    1         NULL             SCHEDULED  0
2    1         1                COMPLETED  1
3    1         1                SCHEDULED  2
4    2         NULL             COMPLETED  0
5    2         1                COMPLETED  1
```

How to filter data such that group 2 rows are not returned using mysql?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the last row of a group in a correlated subquery and compare the `trigger` value:

```
select *
from mytable t
where 'SCHEDULED' = (
  select `trigger`
  from mytable t2
  where t2.group_id = t.group_id
  order by t2.id desc
  limit 1
)
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/976d5/1